# How to trigger an alarm using hours and minutes stored in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, alarm

I have a web app where the user can move two sliders (Using ion range slider) to change the hours and minutes of an alarm which gets stored in local storage.

How do I manipulate the stored values to trigger a real life alarm clock function? Example:

User slides hours and minutes to 13 hours and 13 minutes. They press save. Then at 1:13pm a seperate html will load as an alarm screen with audio.

Below is my codepen for the slider and localstorage functionality:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQoqZB

function for local storage:

```
(function () { 
 from = 0;
 $to.prop("value", 0);
 if (localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes"))  {
 $to.prop("value", localStorage.getItem("StoreMinutes"));
 from = $to.prop;
  } 
   })();
```

Comment: You can use [Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). Is a javascript API that shows notifications to the user desktop

Comment: Will I be able to load a different HTML using this instead of an on page modal? Couldn't find anything about external resources.

Also how would I go about parsing the values of the hours and minutes in local storage to trigger the alarm at that specific time?

Comment: Do you want the script to keep working in the background after you closed the page where you set the alarm? So the page isn't open anymore, and then at the time of the alarm, a new page will open out of nowhere to display/sound the alarm? I'm not sure, but I would assume this is not possible due to security issues to prevent malicious sites to keep working after you close them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by using set interval to check the time in my header (which shows the current time) to compare to the values in my alarm. When they are equal, I triggered the alarm page to show. Hope this helps